# Coverage probability for Uniform$(0, \theta)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, confidence-interval

Let $X_1 \dots X_n$ denote a random sample from a uniform $(0, \theta$) distribution.

**PROBLEM:** 
Compute the coverage probability for the CI: 
$$\left(\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.95}, \frac{X_{(n)}}{0.25}\right)$$ using $W  = X_{(n)}/\theta$ which has density $F_w = w^n$

**My Work**
$$
\begin{split}
CI &= \left(\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.95} \leq \theta \leq  \frac{X_{(n)}}{0.25}\right)\\
&\iff  \left((\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.95} \leq X_{(n)}/w \leq  \frac{X_{(n)}}{0.25}\right)\\
&\iff  \left(\frac{1}{0.95} \leq 1/w \leq  \frac{1}{0.25}\right)
\end{split}
$$
And this is just $P\big(w \in [0.25, 0.95]\big) = F_w(0.95) - F_w(0.25) = 0.95^n - 0.25^n$.

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Please do not delete questions after having received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The coverage probability is the probability that $\theta\in \left(\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.95},\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.25}\right)$.

That is, because $\theta>0$,

\begin{align}
P\left[\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.95}<\theta<\frac{X_{(n)}}{0.25}\right]&=P\left[0.25<\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}<0.95\right]
\\&=P\left[\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}<0.95\right]-P\left[\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}<0.25\right]
\\&=0.95^n-0.25^n
\end{align}